# Linux Lite Problems

Tags: uefi

So, I've been using Linux Lite for a week now. But, I don't really like them. For that, I plan to install my Windows 7 back in the system. I'm sure you guys knew that, you must change the UEFI mode into Legacy. When I'm trying to install Windows 7, it just doesn't boot up of the USB. I've been facing this problem for three days now. I use a legit Windows 7 ISO that I got from Microsoft website itself. I find some solution online but non of them really work. I hope you guys can help me fix this.

Comment: Is that a 32-bit or 64-bit system, and how are you putting the ISO on the USB? Official Windows 7 ISOs are definitely UEFI-compatible, but many "ISO to USB writer" apps aren't.

Comment: It's a 64bit. And I use UNebootin